# Cannot fetch the return value in using axios in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.4, axios

How can i fetch the return value using this code.

```
axios.get('/task')
    .then(response => {
        this.tasks = response.data.tasks;
        return this.tasks;
});
```

It is a possible with this code or is any other means on how I can retrieved the value. I cannot retrieved tha value using the return.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by returning the value like this?

Comment: To create the table for Vue.js together with the search and pagination functionality.

Comment: Please read the documentation on Promise objects. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read about Vue's principle concepts such as its data reactivity system: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

By setting local state like you do (`this.tasks = response.data.tasks;`), view elements react to data changes automagically and render accordingly.

For example, if you have a bunch of tasks that should be rendered, you could have something like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="tasks">
    <div v-for="task in tasks" class="task">{{ task }}<div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Whenever the HTTP request finishes and you set `this.tasks = response.data.tasks`, all of the tasks are automatically rendered. To answer your question: there is really no need to return after the request completes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

```
let base = this;
axios.get('/task')
    .then(response => {
        base.tasks = response.data.tasks;
        return base.tasks;
});
```

Comment: Yes. but still the same. Value does not return using the above code

Comment: are you sure that response.data.tasks is returning you value?

Comment: Here you are using Arrow Syntax that's why your 'this' keyword getting conflict but I used base variable to get parent 'this' and I returned it. thing is make sure that you get value in response.data.tasks

Comment: Yes response.data.tasks. returns a value but when i use the code return this.data.tasks. And call the function. Its returns undefined.

function getTaskData() {
    let base = this;
    axios.get('/task')
        .then(response => {
                base.tasks = response.data.tasks;
                return response.data.tasks;
});

Comment: you can hold it in one variable and then try to return variable